# Incluir propriedades de uma função $.ajax dinamicamente

Tags: jquery, ajax

Existe alguma forma de editar a função do $.ajax para que ele inclua a propriedade "data" quando ela receber um valor, e retire quando não receber? ou seja, dinamicamente? Exemplo:

Quando a variável data possuir valor:

```
var parametro = "{id: "1"}";

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: parametro ,
            async: async,
    ...
```

Quando ela não possuir valor:

```
var parametro = "";

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: async,
    ...
```

Então a minha idéia é algo que funcione como:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            if(parametro)
            {
               data: parametro,
            },           
            async: async,
    ...
```

Eu já tentei passar como:

```
data: undefined ,
data: "",
data: null ,
```

Mas nada funciona. A unica maneira é omitindo a propriedade "data" por completo. Também não encontrei nada similar.

Mais uma coisa, construir duas versões da função, como acima, não é uma opção! Eu preciso fazer dinamicamente.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é simples, repara que o que passas à função ajax é um objeto. Define-o fora da invocação da função e é fácil acrescentar essa propriedade caso precises, assim:

```
var config = {
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: parametro ,
    async: async,
    ...

if (parametro) config.data = parametro;
$.ajax(config);
```

Nesta linha `if (parametro) config.data = parametro;` tens a lógica que querias, onde só acrescenta `data` caso parametro valide `true`.

Comment: e eu aqui pensando em fazer uma `IIFE`, armazenar o $.ajax em uma variavel local do `closure`, e retornar uma função que deleta à propriedade data caso ela esteja vazia. e esta função sobrescrever o `$.ajax` global.

Comment: Boa Sergio. Funcionou como esperado.